# Does Shiny keep "working data Space"?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have a `Shiny-server` working on `Ubuntu 16.04`, with few enterprise Apps I just developed the last month. I'm new working with `Shiny-server`, so I don't have a lot of experience.

I have a route called "K" mounted on my `Ubuntu` server. I have the Databases for the Apps in this directory, so the `App.R` goes there in order to read `.xlsx` files

Let's think, for example, about an App called `app1.R` that uses `BDH.xlsx` as source data file.

My question is: why the app still working on `shiny-server` if I change the name of the `.xlsx` file?

If I change the name of `.xlsx` and call it `"BDH0.xlsx"` (directly from my windows), and then I recharge app with `F5 ¡` the app still working with the data of `BDH.xlsx!` and actually it's name is different.

Can someone explain me why `shiny-server` seems to keep the data 
although I change it's name?

Comment: In shiny server the `global.R` gets reloaded only when you restart the server (with `sudo service shiny-server stop` and `sudo service shiny-server start` from shell). On the other hand, `server.R` and `ui.R` are reloaded each session.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I learnt how global.R works and scoping rules in shiny-server and i made it work! – http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/#scoping